# Fubini's theorem for Stochastic Integral, with sum

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am struggling here with part (2), [image] .

In usual instances, I've had the question phrased like this

[image]

but I'm not sure how to deal with the summation?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{H}$.....?

Comment: http://imgur.com/buchO54

Sorry!

Comment: Need informstion on W also to look into it. Basically, you should be able to work on each term of summation to draw conclusion on the sum.

Comment: @runaround $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. Show that for any random variables $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$$$\left( \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k 1_{(k/n,(k+1)/n]}(t) \right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k^2 1_{(k/n,(k+1)/n]}(t) \tag{1}$$  using the fact that the intervals $(k/n,(k+1)/n]$ are pairwise disjoint.
   2. Applying $(1)$ and Tonelli's theorem yields $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^{\infty} X_n(t)^2 \, dt \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} \mathbb{E}(W(k/n)^2) \, dt. \tag{2}$$
2. Use $W(t) \sim N(0,t)$ to conclude that the right-hand side of $(2)$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks saz! I've worked my way through these parts of the questions, and am now facing this one http://imgur.com/JjOAz0A. Am I right in saying that the E( W(k/n) - W(t) )^2 is (k/n)-t, since W(k/n) - W(t) ∼ N(0,k/n - t)?

Comment: @Dennis Basically, your argumentation is correct. However, if $t \in [k/n,(k+1)n]$, then $$\mathbb{E}([W(k/n)-W(t)]^2) = t-\frac{k}{n}$$ (not $\frac{k}{n}-t$; note that $\frac{k}{n}-t < 0$ for $t \in (k/n,(k+1)/n)$......)